# Double-click to unlock?

Tags: lock-screens

Is there a way to get a lock-screen or set up Android so it unlocks the screen by double-clicking on power-button instead of have to click it first and than slide on touchscreen?

Comment: I've not seen anything like that, and I would think that that would be something that could be accidentally triggered with the phone in your pocket, which may be why it's not (generally) done. That's not to say that it couldn't.

Comment: If something like that exists, you're definitely going to need to be rooted and most likely running a custom ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Done. No need to root. It's now an option in my app: [powerCall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mk.fastcall). Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: 2nd paragraph: Will also what?

Comment: I got it to work like myneur wanted. Only tested in Eclair and Jelly Bean, but should be OK in others. Updated powerCall ver 2.1.5 will be up on GooglePlay in a few hours, which can be easily configured to just unlock on power button double-click. Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution. It does what I wanted, but it is quite slow. Sometimes it flashes twice with delay until the screen is on. Sometimes it shows a black screen and third click is needed to unlock. Tested on xperia active.

Comment: How slow is it on your device? It can be a heavy operation for device to wake up from deep sleep, dismiss keyguard and turn screen on, so I am not surprised. When you just press the power button once after the phone hasn't been used for a while, does it show lock screen instantly or there is a small delay? Anyway, I can try to improve performance and address flashing, but I am afraid small delay will always be there. Email me from the app and I can send you a beta ver if you are interested.